# Django: making a custom PK auto-increment?

Tags: django

I've been using [custom primary keys](http://www.djangoproject.com/documentation/models/custom_pk/) for a model in Django. (This was because I was importing values into the database and they already had ID's attached, and it made sense to preserve the existing values.)

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    transaction_type = models.IntegerField(choices=TRANSACTION_TYPES)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

However, now I want to add new instances of the model to the database, and I'd like to autogenerate a unique primary key. But if I don't specify the ID at the time of creating the instance, I get an error:

```
t = Transaction(transaction_type=0)
t.save()
```

gives:

```
IntegrityError at /page
(1048, "Column 'id' cannot be null")
```

How can I autogenerate a unique ID to specify for new values, without having to alter the way I import the existing values?

**UPDATE**

I've written this custom method, which seems to work...

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            i = Transaction.objects.all().order_by('-id')[0]
            self.id = i.id+1
        super(Transaction, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I'm curious - what was the problem of having django handle the primary key if you are doing bulk import? I have never had the situation where the primary key was the problem - unless you are importing on a production/running system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you importing the existing values? It would be trivial to write something into your `Transaction`s `__init__` to generate a new ID for you, but without knowing how you're importing the other values I can't say for sure whether it will alter the way you work with them.

Comment: Not sure if this answers your question, but: from a CSV file, using a custom import script, and setting the Transaction ID field to the ID in the CSV file. (Also: I import them using Django objects rather than direct SQL.)  Does that help?

Comment: Yes. Instead of writing your `Transaction`s `__init__`, override `save()` so that it first checks if it has an ID, and then if it doesn't it generates a new one for you (and then calls save as usual).

Comment: I've had a go at overriding `save()` and added as an update above - please could you tell me if this looks vaguely sensible, and then I'll accept your answer? thanks!

Comment: It looks good - you might run into issues if you happen to generate a Transaction with ID 10 and then import one with ID 10, but that's the only problem I can see cropping up (and how you solve that one is up to you).

Comment: That's fine, because the importing is a one-off that happens before I create any new transactions through the web app. Thanks a lot!

Comment: On reflection... I have a slight concern about race conditions. Is it possible that two people could call save() simultaneously, and end up with the same ID, or crash Django? (I guess Django must have a workaround for this in its own save() method?)

Comment: It's definitely possible that a race condition could crop up - although as far as I know, it shouldn't crash Django (maybe just throw a database error for the second user).

Answer (score 4):

You can use `AutoField` for the column `id` instead of `IntegerField`. The following should work for you:

```
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```

`id` will now increase automatically and won't have concurrency problems as it may encounter in `save` method.

Answer (score 4):

I've ended up using very similar piece of code, but have made it slightly more generic:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.id is None:
        self.id =  self.__class__.objects.all().order_by("-id")[0].id + 1
    super(self.__class__, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

it uses `self.__class__` so you can just copy paste this code to any model class without changing anything.

Comment: brilliant thank you, the thing about `models.autofield` is that I cannot start it with an initial value

Answer (score 1):

If you remove your declared id field, django will automatically assume this:

```
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```

In Django 1.8, `inspectdb` will automatically detect `auto_increment` and use an `AutoField` when generating models.

Answer (score 0):

Django migrations will do most of the hard work for you here.

Firstly, stop any access to your app so users can't change the database whilst you are working on it.

**It would then be very wise to backup your database, before performing any work, as a precaution.**

Remove your manually declared `id` field from your models.py (i.e. delete it).

Run `makemigrations` and then `migrate`. Django will modify the id field to the correct implementation for your database version.

Run this (example) command in *psql* adapting, if need be, to your table names:

```
select setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('transactions_transaction', 'id'), max(id)) from transactions_transaction;
```

This will set your `id` field to the correct serial sequence value in postgres for your table (i.e. the largest value of the `id` field of your existing records). This is crucial, as otherwise the value will be 1!

And that's it: from now on everything will be automatic again.